# What kind of vulnerabilities involve the attacker sending "php://input"?

Tags: php, security

My site was just bombarded by an attacker trying to pass "php://input" into any GET/POST variable they could think of. If this is trying to take advantage of a vulnerability, I'm unaware of it. What could this user be trying to exploit?

Comment: I didn't think "php://" was a protocol... is that legit or just some garbage string being pushed in by the attacker?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: `php://input` is the PHP input stream. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007-Malicious_File_Execution

php://input reads data from the incoming request. Basically, what the attacker might be trying to do is pass "php://input" into a weak php directive such as:

```
include $_REQUEST['filename'];
```

It would allow the attacker to send the "contents" of the php file to execute via the request, thereby allowing him to execute php code on your machine

Comment: That's kind of what I thought, along the same lines as how Stephen Fry's Twitter account was hacked (http://eng.xakep.ru/link/50643/). Quite the odd way to go about the attack, but I suppose brute-forcing is cheaper than brain power.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps anyone who runs an eval on php input?

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
eval($data);
```

I have not seen this personally but I bet someones done it at some point thinking it could be safe.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an attempt to force evaluation of PHP code passed through raw request data - seems a bit hopeful though.